# How to add a date filter to an Aggregation query in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm currently doing an aggregation query that groups all tracking id's and produces their count. I want to be able to filter this query by date.

my working query:

```
users = Tracking.objects.values( 'tracking_id' ).annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id')).order_by('-dcount')[:100]
```

I've tried the following filter combinations but all result in syntax errors.

```
start_date = datetime.date(2012, 2, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2012, 3, 2)
users = Tracking.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date).values( 'tracking_id' ).annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id')).order_by('-dcount')[:100]
```

and

```
start_date = datetime.date(2012, 2, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2012, 3, 2)
users = Tracking.objects.values( 'tracking_id' ).filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date).annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id')).order_by('-dcount')[:100]
```

and

```
start_date = datetime.date(2012, 2, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2012, 3, 2)
users = Tracking.objects.values( 'tracking_id' ).annotate(dcount=Count('tracking_id')).filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date).order_by('-dcount')[:100]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they result in syntax error because of a missing parenthesis (after end_date):

```
users = Tracking.objects.values( 'tracking_id' ).filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date) ...
```

should be

```
users = Tracking.objects.values( 'tracking_id' ).filter(date__range=(start_date, end_date)) ...
```

Comment: Perhaps you just need a cup of coffee :) and you're welcome !